# Python: How to correctly specify position in several lists?

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

I'm writing a program where all the data has come in one big file and I need to split it into sections and then work on those sections individually. The data is in 3 parts, the day it was taken (or the "epoch"), the wavelength and the flux. I currently have:

```
epoch=[]
wavelength=[]
flux=[]

text_file = open("data.dat", "r")
lines1 = text_file.read()
#print lines1
text_file.close()

a = [float(x) for x in lines1.split()]

a1=0
a2=1
a3=2

while a1<len(a):
    epoch.append(int(a[a1]))
    wavelength.append(float(a[a2]))
    flux.append(float(a[a3]))
    a1+=3
    a2+=3
    a3+=3

print epoch

x=[]
y=[]
z=[]

for i in epoch:
    if epoch[i] == epoch[i+1]:
        x.append(epoch[i])
        y.append(wavelength[i])
        z.append(flux[i])
        i+=1
    #print x, y, z

    #else integrate, i+=1
```

where integrate is a function I have already prepared.

When I run this, the results are 3 lists of the end value of the data for the 3 different measurements, eg [1000, 1000, 1000, 1000] instead of [970, 980, 990, 1000]. I want to tell it that if the value of the epoch is different, then integrate over the range of values with the same epoch value and then start the process again for the next epoch value.

I think the problem is that I'm not specifying the positions in the lists properly but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give a sample of data u r using ?

Comment: I think there's a bug in your code, "for i in epoch:" gives you epochs, not the index of values in epoch but then you use it as an index.

Comment: it's always a bad idea, to put data, that belongs together in different lists. Use list of lists instead.

Comment: is your `data.dat` three values per line, or really a mess of numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the bottom for loop, you're iterating over the values of epoch rather than the indexes of those values. You could put a 'print(i)' statement inside the loop to see this for yourself. Here is code that properly iterates over indexes:

```
for i in xrange(len(x)):
    if (i + 1) < len(x) and epoch[i] == epoch[i+1]:
    ...
```

I fixed another bug where on the last iteration of the loop you'd attempt to access an index beyond the end of the list. There might be other problems with this code -- this is just a first pass.

Answer (score 0):

First read in the data and make a list of three-tuples (epoch, wavelength, flux).
Then group the data together with same epoch.
Then do what you want.

```
import itertools

with open("data.dat", "r") as text_file:
    data = text_file.read()

data = zip(*[(float(z) for z in data)]*3)

for epoch, group in itertools.groupby(data, lambda x:x[0]):
    group = list(group)
    print group
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it sounds like you want a dict of epochs, with each entry containing a list of wavelength/flux values.

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)

with open('data.dat') as stream:
    for line in stream:
        entry = line.split()
        data[int(entry[0])].append((float(entry[1]), float(entry[2])))

for epoch, values in data.items():
    y, z = list(zip(*values))
    print('epoch:', epoch)
    print('  wavelength:', y)
    print('  flux:', z)
```